# How to use variable in different playbook?

Tags: ansible

How to use a variable in a different playbook? (ansible 2.7.10)

**username.yml**

```
- hosts: host
  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: 'Username...'
      private: no
  tasks:
  - name: Show username
    debug:
      msg: "{{username}}"

- import_playbook: dns.yml
```

**dns.yml**

```
- hosts: DNS
  tasks:
    - name: Mesaj
      debug:
         msg: "{{username}}"
```

> FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'username' is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of a variable declared by *vars_prompt* is the **play**. Use [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html#set-fact-set-host-facts-from-a-task) to share such variable in the whole **playbook**.

> The set_fact module takes key=value pairs as variables to set in the **playbook scope**.

```
- hosts: host
  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: 'Username...'
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: Show username
      debug:
        msg: "{{ username }}"
    - set_fact:
        username: "{{ username }}"
```

In the second play (dns.yml) use [hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#caching-facts) to reference the variables cached by *host* in the first play.

```
- hosts: DNS
  tasks:
    - name: Mesaj
      debug:
         msg: "{{ hostvars['host'].username }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without disturbing the `dns.yml` playbook. So, you can pass `-e username=myuser` and execute it separately if needed.

#### username.yml

Adding set fact with different variable name (uname) and passing it to the playbook (dns.yml)

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: 'Username...'
      private: no
  tasks:
  - name: Show username
    debug:
      msg: "{{username}}"
  - name: Set fact
    set_fact:
      uname: "{{ username }}"

- import_playbook: dns.yml
  vars:
    username: "{{ uname }}"
```

#### dns.yml

No change to this playbook.

```
- hosts: DNS
  tasks:
    - name: Mesaj
      debug:
         msg: "{{username}}"
```